# GoDaddy WordPress site Switched to HTTPS now get ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: https, wordpress, godaddy

I have a website www.intelli.bet that is a hosted WordPress site.

I need to start taking payments on the website so 30 minutes ago I bought an SSL certificate from GoDaddy, activated it and now when I try to load the page I get:

```
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

The same message comes up in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Is this something that's likely to resolve itself, sort of like DNS propagation? Or do I need to change some settings in my WordPress? Hopefully not as I can no longer access it!

EDIT:

I just had to wait a little longer. I think it was just under 2 hours before I tried a refresh and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have SSL currently installed on that domain.

Input your domain here, to check for any issues with SSL.

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Since you don't have SSL installed, and you are redirecting your http to https, it is not showing any page, but the "This site can’t provide a secure connection" error.

If your site is hosted on GoDaddy check with them, why is it not installed, if you only purchased SSL from them, be sure to install it on your hosting provider server.

While you resolve SSL issues, disable your http > https redirect, to see your site over http.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but in the time it took for me to eat a pizza the whole problem resolved itself.